# Unable to load data in combobox store in extjs with a memory proxy

Tags: java, spring-mvc, extjs

I am using Extjs 6. I want to get data from server and load data to combobox. But when I get data root property and success value is not comes with data still its goes in success call but unable to load data to combobox.

Any help would be appreciated!

Below are code snippets:
I have combobox as below :

```
xtype           : 'thrcombobox',
 fieldLabel     : 'Select District',
 store          :  Ext.create('thr.store.admin.master.DistrictStore'),
 itemId         : 'cmbDistrict',
 name           : 'cmbDistrict',
 displayField   : 'districtMarathi',
 valueField     : 'districtID',
 queryMode      : 'local'
```

Below is Store :

```
Ext.define('thr.store.admin.master.DistrictStore',{
     extend         : 'Ext.data.Store',
     alias          : 'store.districtStore',
     storeId        : 'districtStore',
     requires       : [
         'thr.model.admin.master.District'
     ],
     model       : 'thr.model.admin.master.District',
     autoSync    : false,
     autoLoad    : false,
     proxy: {
           type : 'memory',
           reader   : {
              type  : 'json',
              rootProperty: 'data'
           }
     }   
});
```

Below is Model :

```
Ext.define('thr.model.admin.master.District',{
    extend      : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields      : [
        {
            name : 'districtID'
        },
        {
            name : 'districtMarathi'
        },
        {
            name : 'districtEnglish'
        }
    ]
});
```

And below is ajax call where I am getting data for store:

```
var districtStore = districtCombobox.getStore();
districtStore.loadData([]);
```

Above districtStore defines store of combobox.

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: <path goes here..>,
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(response, action){
                    var decodedResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    if(!Ext.isEmpty(decodedResponse) && decodedResponse.success){
                            districtStore.loadData(decodedResponse.data);
                    }
                },
                failure: function(form, action){
                     return false;
                }

    });
```

Comment: Pl someone help me.

Comment: You can try to let autoLoad  as true and remove this: districtStore.loadData([]);